# How should I prevent negative integers in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have a method with a integer parameter and I want to allow only positive or nonnegative integers. What is the best way to achieve this restriction? I have tried with annotations but they do not work.

I want it to throw exception if it is a negative number.

```
public List<UserEntity> findUsersCreatedInTheLast(@NonNull @Min(value = 0) @Valid @Positive Integer minutes) {
```

Comment: can you provide a simple reproductive example with annotations that not work in your case ?

Comment: Back in the day we had to write lines of code without IDE's while going down the page both ways each time.

Comment: Posts on stackoverflow get nothing from me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@min annotation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330611/min-annotation-not-working)

Comment: `if (minutes == null || minutes < 0) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }` should do it. But if it can't be `null`, then it should really be `int minutes` (or better yet: `Duration duration`).

Comment: @K.Nicholas I wish Java had positive integer type.

Comment: @ilhan - lol, good luck with that. I think if you follow the above link you'll see that somehow a validator needs to be invoked. I didn't look closer but that makes sense to me.

Comment: @K.Nicholas, no, it is not very clear what library they are using and unfortunately that one is for properties of objects.

Comment: Where does @Min come from? `hibernate-validator`? If so, what makes you think it belongs on some random method parameter?

Comment: @K.Nicholas, I think it was jakarta.validation.constraints.Min.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293185/validate-positive-integers

Comment: @pdem, those answers are about properties of objects but I am asking for method parameters

Comment: @ihan let the tag "bean-validation" it's related to the annotation you use, also need the context of the class, you need `@validated`and `@service`on the class : on this example the validation is on method too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755608/springboot-validation-of-a-bean-method-parameters-and-return

Comment: Do you mean [`jakarta.validation.constraints.Positive`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.0/jakarta-bean-validation-spec-3.0#builtinconstraints-positive)?

Comment: @pdem, so it looks like whether it works or not is dependent on when an object is created.

Comment: @ilhan Please add your pom.xml

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using `hibernate-validator` dependency in your project and I suspect that you are trying to use the **JSR-303** annotations to validate.

You have to use `@Validated` to enable the method parameter validation and to make JSR-303 annotations work in Spring.

Sample code to demonstrate:

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.PositiveOrZero;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Validated
public class UserDAO {

  public List<UserEntity> findUsersCreatedInTheLast(@NonNull 
                                           @PositiveOrZero Integer minutes) {
     // logic
  }

}
```

This will throw exception like this when negative number is passed:

> jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException:
> findUsersCreatedInTheLast.minutes: must be greater than or equal to 0

**Note:** Use `@PositiveOrZero` annotation. It's much shorter to use.

**Update:**

My pom.xml for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-mysql</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Just add only these dependencies to your spring boot app.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I have tested. This will work 100%.

Comment: It said "Unable to create a Configuration, because no Jakarta Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath." then after I have added some dependencies it says "HV000183: Unable to initialize 'jakarta.el.ExpressionFactory'.". I am giving up. In my opinion it works only under some conditions.

Comment: @ilhan Add the hibernate-validator dependency.

Comment: @ilhan `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Comment: @ilhan No. it works. I don't know what are you doing. But if you want I can provide a code sample via github

Comment: @ilhan I'm updating my answer with the pom.xml

Comment: @ilhan I have added the full pom.xml for spring boot app that I have created.

Comment: @ilhan For this issue HV000183: Unable to initialize 'jakarta.el.ExpressionFactory, look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386771/javax-validation-validationexception-hv000183-unable-to-load-javax-el-express